# What is the best way to use unmanaged c++ dll class from c#

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, dll, word-wrap

I am searching for the best and elegant way to use `c++ class from C# /ASP .Net` application.

I read this article [How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class) and wondering if there is a simple and right way to use it because this article is from 2007.

Comment: primarily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: The _best_ (whatever it may means, in this case I'd say easiest) way is to write a managed wrapper with C++/CLI. You will export a nice and safe managed interface to your native DLL and in C# you will use like any other managed assembly. P/Invoke isn't easy and to P/Invoke C++ classes is from _impossible_ to _terribly complicate_. Else?

Comment: The reason it tends to be opinion based is because you have so (too) many options. Next to a C++/CLI wrapper, you could as well wrap the native code into a COM object. Also, you could use the native function mechanism inherent to C#. Last not least, F# also offers some nice options. I stay out of any recommendation as I found that each approach has its own up and downsides.

Comment: I forgot to mention a few options, specific to asp.net. E.g. fastcgi or vintage cgi. Also you could write a http server around your native code and then provide the data/functionality of the native code in a REST-ful manner.

Comment: SWIG might also be an option if you have the header files.

Comment: tanks, it help. about  BitTickler comment can you please extend your example to asp.net?